# SparkSQL between timestamp in where(filter) clause (V.S. In MySQL)

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

**Describe:**
I have a table with timestamp column and i want to get the number of values where the timestamp in specific time window.

My code is as shown in here:

```
String startTime = "2018-08-08 00:00:00";
String endTime = "2018-08-08 23:59:59";
productDF.where("CREATETIME >= '" + startTime + "' AND CREATETIME <= '" + endTime + "'").count();
```

I also tried `between...and...`sentence; and also:

```
productDF.where(unix_timestamp(col("CREATETIME"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
                    .cast("timestamp")
                    .between(
                            Timestamp.valueOf(startTime),
                            Timestamp.valueOf(endTime)
                    )).count();
```

The result i get is **6843**.

But when i operate the sql sentence using Navicat:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table 
WHERE CREATETIME BETWEEN '2018-08-08 00:00:00' and '2018-08-08 23:59:59';
```

it shows **7689**.

**Problem:**
I want to know why i get the different results in Spark and Mysql.....what am i missing here??

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The problem happened because of the **TIMEZONE**.
In spark env., it get the timezone from_unixtime..So need to set the config.

```
.config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```

But I still don't understand why the spark sql session flow the system timezone instead of just select from the column.....

Comment: The column has a TZ, like it or not. Just ask your Navicat thing to show the timestamps with the TZ used -- maybe the tool does not set the client-side TZ and uses whatever the server has for default... While Spark does, as is expected.

Comment: Recommended reading: _"Falsehoods programmers believe about time"_ 
https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time (2 parts)

Comment: Recommended reading: _"Working with timezones"_ https://davecturner.github.io/2018/08/12/working-with-timezones.html

Comment: Also, note that the Spark property you are using is _very_ recent, if I'm not mistaken. Not long ago, if your driver and executors were on different servers with different TZ set by default... It could get weird.